# Utilizar variáveis externas ao Route do Laravel 5 para enviar à view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Olá, estou trabalhando com o `Laravel`, e no meu arquivo de Rotas, eu gostaria de deixar criada uma variável que quero usar em todas as rotas, assim:

**/routes/web.php**

```
$foo = "ola mundo";

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('page1', ["title" => "teste - $foo"]); //concatenação direta
});
Route::get('/page2', function () {
    return view('page2', ["title" => "bar - ".$foo]);  //concatenação por mesclagem
});
```

Meu problema é que (o que não faz sentido...) o `Laravel` não está conseguindo encontrar a variável `$foo`, mesmo ela estando declarada antes das estruturas de rotas e no próprio arquivo de configuração.

Independente do tipo de concatenação que uso, o `Laravel` não entende e me apresenta o erro:

> ErrorException (E_NOTICE). Undefined variable: foo

Como resolver?

**EDIT:**
Fiz um teste definindo uma variável customizada dentro do arquivo `.env` e chamando ela através do método `env('CUSTOM_FOO')` que o `Laravel` disponibiliza e não tive nenhum problema, mas em uma variável criada no próprio arquivo (e que pelo meu entender de `PHP` deveria ter sido encontrada) não funciona...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As variáveis externas a uma função anônima não são visíveis dentro delas, para que você possa utilizar esta variável dentro de uma função anônima você precisa utilizar o `use()` após a chamada da função, veja:

```
$foo = 'foo';
Route::get('/', function () use ($foo) {
    return view('page1', ["title" => "bar - ".$foo]);
});
```

> Desta maneira, a variável será acessada somente para leitura

Caso você precise alterar a variável externa à uma função anônima, você precisará passa-la por referência:

```
$foo = 'foo';
Route::get('/', function () use (&$foo) {
    return view('page1', ["title" => "bar - ".$foo]); 
});
```

Comment: excelente, muito obrigado!!! acabou que eu preferi deixar dentro do arquivo `.env` mesmo porque assim posso usar essa declaração estática em outros locais do sistema, mas muito obrigado mesmo assim...

Comment: sim, eu recomendaria isso mesmo @LeandroLuk